# OracleBulkCopy from CSV - Can not insert null column has value

Tags: c#, oracle, csv, oracle10g, bulkinsert

I am using OracleBlukCopy to dump a huge CSV file into the database table. Here is the code I am using. When I run this I am getting an error saying cannot insert NULL into TBL_COL1, but my CSV has values for TBL_COL1.

After research I came to conclusion that it is giving an error when TBL_COL1 has characters in it. Any idea why?

```
DataTable datatable = TranslateCSVFileToDataTable();

using (OracleConnection connectiontodb = new OracleConnection(databaseconnectionstring))
{
    connectiontodb.Open();
    using (OracleBulkCopy copytothetable = new OracleBulkCopy(connectiontodb))
    {
        copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL1", "TBL_COL1"); 
        copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL2", "TBL_COL2"); 
        copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL3", "TBL_COL3"); 
        copytothetable.DestinationTableName = "DESTINATION_TABLE";
        copytothetable.WriteToServer(datatable);
    }
}


CREATE TABLE DESTINATION_TABLE
(
  TBL_COL1                   VARCHAR2(32) not null,
  TBL_COL2                   DATE not null,
  TBL_COL3                   DATE not null,
)


98987987987987987,6/23/2014,7/23/2014
98987987987987987,7/23/2014,8/21/2014
98987987987987987,8/21/2014,9/22/2014
98987987987987987,9/22/2014,10/21/2014
98987987987987987,10/21/2014,11/20/2014
98987987987987987,11/20/2014,12/22/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,1/8/2014,1/9/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,1/9/2014,2/9/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,2/9/2014,3/9/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,3/9/2014,4/7/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,4/7/2014,5/7/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,5/7/2014,6/8/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,6/8/2014,7/8/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,7/8/2014,8/7/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,8/7/2014,9/8/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,9/8/2014,10/7/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,10/7/2014,11/9/2014
656666666666666ABC1234,11/9/2014,12/7/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,5/7/2014,6/8/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,6/8/2014,7/8/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,7/8/2014,8/7/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,8/7/2014,9/8/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,9/8/2014,10/7/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,10/7/2014,11/9/2014
777777777777777XYZ1234,11/9/2014,12/7/2014
```

Comment: Might you have an empty line in your csv?

Comment: did you try debugging your datatable...check to see if you datatable has any values.

Comment: @Politank-Z TRAILING NULLCOLS in the control file

Comment: @prasy datatable has got values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try oracle transaction commit. Maybe this helps to you.

```
using (OracleConnection connectiontodb = new OracleConnection(databaseconnectionstring))
    {
        connectiontodb.Open();
        using (OracleBulkCopy copytothetable = new OracleBulkCopy(connectiontodb))
        {
    OracleTransaction tran = connectiontodb.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
          try
          {
            copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL1", "TBL_COL1"); 
            copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL2", "TBL_COL2"); 
            copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add("TBL_COL3", "TBL_COL3"); 
            copytothetable.DestinationTableName = "DESTINATION_TABLE";
            copytothetable.WriteToServer(datatable);
            tran.Commit();
          }
          catch
          {
            tran.Roolback();
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the Datatable columns as similar to DESTINATION_TABLE columns and then do the column mappings

```
DataTable datatable;
            datatable = new DataTable("temptable");
            datatable.Columns.Add("TBL_COL1 ");
            datatable.Columns.Add("TBL_COL2 ");
            datatable.Columns.Add("TBL_COL3");
using (OracleBulkCopy copytothetable = new OracleBulkCopy(connectiontodb))
{
   copytothetable .DestinationTableName = "DESTINATION_TABLE";
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
      foreach (DataColumn col in datatable.Columns)
      {
         if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
         {
            copytothetable.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
          }
       }
    }
    copytothetable.WriteToServer(datatable);
}
```